# Как добавить таймер в консольное приложение?

Tags: c#

Помогите разобраться, у меня есть консольное приложение с событиями, необходимо эти события вызывать при наступлении определенного времени, например сегодня в 14:00 часа, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: 1. Используйте планировщик Windows (или какая там у вас ОС). 2. Есть класс System.Threading.Timer, который можно использовать в любых приложениях

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 способа.

1. System.Thread.Timer:

```
private static Timer timer;
public static void Main()
{
    DateTime endTime = new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);
    Timer timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, endTime.Ticks);
    Thread.Sleep(10000); //Что-то там работает-работает
}
private static void TimerCallback(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("дзын дзыц, время: " + DateTime.Now);
    timer.Dispose();
}
```

2. System.Thread:

```
private void SetTimer(Action action, TimeSpan time) => new Thread(() => {
    Thread.Sleep(time);
    action.Invoke();
}).Start();
```